# PHP MySQL Function Unit Testing

Tags: php, mysql, unit-testing, phpunit, simpletest

I need to test a number of functions that I have created using PHP 5 which carry out the required database CRUD type actions (SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE) which are required by my web application.

I have been looking at PHP unit testing suites such as Simple Test and PHP Unit which seem to offer what I need however I am unsure how I am meant to achieve this, as equivalence partitioning and boundary analysis isn't all that clear. Do I just need to input different variables and vary this? This seems rather pointless as a string that is different may not necessarily make any difference.

Any guidance on this would be helpful as I have not encountered this before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are testing the interaction between your PHP code and your MySQL database, you are performing integration testing, rather than unit testing.

Here are some examples of integration testing with [Enhance PHP framework](http://www.enhance-php.com/), it tests a repository class that saves and retrieves a Tenant object.

Instead of running against a pre-populated database, it runs on an entirely empty database and creates and destroys the tables as it goes using a simple table helper. This removes the dependency on particular data being in the right state in a test database, which is hard to keep in step.

```
<?php
class TenantRepositoryTestFixture extends EnhanceTestFixture {
    private $Target;

    public function SetUp() {
        $tables = new TableHelper();
        $tables->CreateTenantTable();
        $this->Target = Enhance::GetCodeCoverageWrapper('TenantRepository');
    }

    public function TearDown() {
        $tables = new TableHelper();
        $tables->DropTenantTable();
    }

    public function SaveWithNewTenantExpectSavedTest() {
        $tenant = new Tenant();
        $tenant->Name = 'test';

        $saved = $this->Target->Save($tenant);
        $result = $this->Target->GetById($saved->Id);

        Assert::AreNotIdentical(0, $result->Id);
        Assert::AreIdentical($tenant->Name, $result->Name);
    }

    public function SaveWithExistingTenantExpectSavedTest() {
        $tenant = new Tenant();
        $tenant->Name = 'test';
        $saved = $this->Target->Save($tenant);
        $saved->Name = 'changed';
        $saved = $this->Target->Save($saved);

        $result = $this->Target->GetById($saved->Id);

        Assert::AreIdentical($saved->Id, $result->Id);
        Assert::AreIdentical($saved->Name, $result->Name);
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally the idea with unit testing is to ensure that, if you make a change, you can simply run a simple series of tests to ensure no existing functionality will break. So that said, you'll want to cover the typical data you're expecting, as well as edge/boundary cases, which might include strings with quotes (to verify that they're being escaped properly), SQL injection attacks (same), empty strings, strings of different encoding, NULL, a boolean `true`, etc. Each test should verify that, given the data you input, you're getting the expected result, in this case (respectively): escaped string inserted, escaped string inserted, empty string inserted, different encoding converted or thrown out then inserted, an error thrown on a NULL value, the string 'true' inserted, etc.

I haven't used either test framework in a few years, but I remember having good results with PHPUnit.